# Pytorch accessing data points in a data batch

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I'm trying to run my model on selected data points in a data batch, but the model generates completely different outputs from directly running on the batch.

Here's an example:
I have a data batch (`firstData`) with shape `torch.Size([128, 1, 28, 28])`, which means it contains 128 data points.
`firstData` is retrieved by:

```py
for _, (data, _) in enumerate(train_loader):
    firstData = data
    break
```

`train_loader` is a `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` on MNIST dataset
Then I run:

```py
with torch.no_grad():
    print(cnn(firstData.cuda())[0:2]) # run on batch and get first 2 outputs
```

and it outputs:

```
tensor([[-0.5045, -0.8611, -1.0237, -2.2146,  1.6829, -0.1202,  8.2230, -2.9030,
         -0.6736, -1.6260],
        [-1.6367, -0.0683,  2.3553, -2.8480,  8.0057, -2.7570, -0.7046, -1.3720,
         -1.1558,  0.2683]], device='cuda:0')
```

When I run:

```py
with torch.no_grad():
    print(cnn(firstData.cuda()[0:2])) # select first 2 data points and run the model
```

and it outputs:

```
tensor([[ 0.8256, -1.2180, -2.2164, -0.3754, -1.9170,  2.4913,  4.2119, -2.6611,
          1.1260, -0.2956],
        [-1.1582,  0.8964,  3.2793, -0.4405,  2.4863, -2.9732, -3.5990,  1.8273,
         -0.6883,  0.3878]], device='cuda:0')
```

Additionally, `cnn` is a resnet18 like structure and is already trained to 0.99 accuracy on the MNIST dataset. I also made `cnn` deterministic and it always returns the same results given the same inputs.

I'm new to Pytorch and I guess it is because I'm accessing the batched data in a wrong way. Can anyone give some suggestions to solve that?

**Update**
Thanks @kHarshit ! Calling `cnn.eval()` solved my problem.

In a PyTorch tutorial [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#load):
"Remember that you must call `model.eval()` to set dropout and batch normalization layers to evaluation mode before running inference. Failing to do this will yield inconsistent inference results. If you wish to resuming training, call `model.train()` to ensure these layers are in training mode."

This makes sense because my `cnn` contains `BatchNorm2d` layers.

Official API can be found [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.eval)

Comment: Did you set `cnn.eval()`?

Comment: No, I didn't set it

Comment: is shuffle in data loader set to true?

Comment: you need to set model to eval mode.